# How to show tooltip? I have tried everything but I have no solution yet

Tags: c#, console-application, autoit

```
class Programmer
{
    private const string StrTip = "Hello world";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoItX3 Auto = new();

        while (true)
        {
            Auto.Sleep(1000);
            Auto.ToolTip(StrTip);
        }
    }
}
```

How to show a tooltip? I used 1 AutoIt library the program is still running but not showing the tooltip?

Comment: u cant show tooltip in a console app

Comment: Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Where/why do you want to show the tooltip on console app?

Comment: i want to get the coordinates when scrolling to make a tooltip every time i scroll to an app @Chetan